# How do I fix LXQt Appearance Configuration?

Tags: lubuntu, themes

LXQt Appearance Configuration changed by itself. Icons theme changed from Papyrus Dark to Oxygen. I tried to change it back, however, it remains the same. LXQt theme also remains the same. I installed Lubuntu 18.10 a couple days ago in two machines, and this issue happened to both at the same time. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug in ~/.config/lxqt/lxqt.conf due to LXQt Appearance changing immediately after selecting an option.
Just restore the file, considering someone has a good one.